# Paste together two character vectors of different lengths

Tags: r, paste

I have two different character vectors in R, that I want to combine to use for column names:

```
groups <- c("Group A", "Group B")
label <- c("Time","Min","Mean","Max")
```

When I try using paste I get the result:

```
> paste(groups,label)
[1] "Group A Time" "Group B Min"  "Group A Mean" "Group B Max"
```

Is there a simple function or setting that can paste these together to get the following output?

```
[1] "Group A Time" "Group A Min"  "Group A Mean" "Group A Max"  "Group B Time"
[6] "Group B Min"  "Group B Mean" "Group B Max"
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably `outer` helps your work. Try this:

```
> c(t(outer(groups, label, paste)))
[1] "Group A Time" "Group A Min"  "Group A Mean" "Group A Max"  "Group B Time" "Group B Min" 
[7] "Group B Mean" "Group B Max"
```

Comment: Found the tip to enclosing everything with a t() especially useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`outer`

outer(groups, labels, FUN=paste)

Answer (score 1):

Since it's two element array, I would do

```
 c(paste(groups[1],label),paste(groups[2],label))
```